# The network path was not found error while run application on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had an error in my code when i run this on to the web server given below

This shows an error that `network path was not found`.
 Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 public class Connection
 {
  public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=173.192.96.130;Initial Catalog=hrmodule;Integrated Security=false;user=hrmodule1;password=hrmodule@123");

    SqlConnection getconnection()
    {
        return con;
    }
    public void openconn()
    {
        **con.Open();** the error occur on this line

    }
    public void closeconn()
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    public DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, getconnection());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    public void Storepro(string sp, string[] pn, string[] pt, string[] pv, int nos)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        for (int i = 0; i < nos; i++)
        {
            switch (pt[i])
            {
                case "string":
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pn[i], pv[i]);
                    break;
                case "int":
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pn[i], Convert.ToInt32(pv[i]));
                    break;
                case "decimal":
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pn[i], Convert.ToDecimal(pv[i]));
                    break;
                case "DateTime":
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pn[i], Convert.ToDateTime(pv[i]));
                    break;
            }

        }
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }


 }
```

Comment: Show your code.. Show your error..Give us more information..

Comment: Where is your code buddy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you access 173.192.96.130 from the machine running the code?

Comment: this is database server ip where database is stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=173.192.96.130;Initial Catalog=hrmodule;Integrated Security=false;user=hrmodule1;password=hrmodule@123"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

In your c# page remove

```
 public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=173.192.96.130;Initial Catalog=hrmodule;Integrated Security=false;user=hrmodule1;password=hrmodule@123");
```

And add

```
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
```

Comment: in web config file it should be datasource in place of server

Comment: You can change it to your convenience. I just gave the hint.

Comment: If you problem is solved then please tick the right mark for my answer :P